# Merge two states in Vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a Vuex store with two states.

- notes (notes that have been synced with the server/DB)
- localNotes (which has not been synced with the server/DB, when synced with the server/DB they will be moved to 'notes' state)

I am using these states to show the notes in a list with a getter. This getter merges the two objects and return the merge objects

The problem I have now is that if I add a new note to one of the states it will not be shown in the note list because the getter doesn't pick the 'change' up. I think this happens because I return a variable instead of a function.

This is my getter:

```
const getters = {
    notesObject: (state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) => {
        let result = {};
        let mergedObject = {...state.notes, ...state.localNotes};
        Object.keys(mergedObject).forEach(key => {
            const item = mergedObject[key];
            if (rootGetters['tags/activeKey'] === null) {
                result[key] = item
            } else if (item.tag_id === rootGetters['tags/activeKey']) {
                result[key] = item
            }
        });
        return result;
    },
};
```

Example object:

```
example: {
            5: {
                title: 'Testing title',
                text: 'text'
            },
            6: {
                title: 'Testing title',
                text: 'text'
            }
        }
```

I hope someone can help me out to find the best solution for this. I was thinking about using a watcher, but I know these need to be avoided.

A solution was to let the watcher merge the two states into a new state.
Then the getter doesn't have to merge the two objects

Comment: Can you show how you add new notes? I can't see any problem with the code that you shared.

Comment: What does your mutation look like?

Comment: this is the mutation: state.localNotes[payload.id] = payload;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vue's [reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) system doesn't detect adding new properties. Try using `Vue.set(object, key, value)` when adding new notes.

In your mutation function replace `state.localObject[payload.id] = payload;` with `Vue.set(state.localObject, payload.id, payload);` The getter should then work properly.

Comment: Should I always use Vue.set and Vue.delete for adding and deleting to an object?

Comment: In general that's good advice to follow when you run into those limitations